# Could I see the corner of the room?

Tags: optics, reflection

Could I see the corner of the room I'm in, if all walls had the same color and were perfect Lambertian reflectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any even remotely realistic light source, you could. Seeing the corners has less to do with how the walls reflect the light, and more with how much light hits the surface in the first place.

Let's assume the light source is in the center of a cubic room and shines isotropically in all directions. The centers of the walls will be closest to the light, and therefore be illuminated with the most light per unit of surface area. The further we go into the corners, the shallower the angle between the direction of the light and the wall. Consequently, these areas are darker.

The only way you could not see the corners even in this idealized situation was if your light source was anisotropic in a way that exactly compesates for this effect, which is specific to the room geometry and position of the light source.

Comment: Convincing, thanks! But without light dilution? If using a flash light this effect was largely refuced, and with a laser pointer almost non-existent anymore (which can be easily tested)?

Comment: I think with a flashlight the effect would still be quite noticable, but more importantly, you would see the deformation of the light cone on the surface as it changes direction in a corner. Even if you move a laser pointer across a corner, you will still notice the dot changing direction even though you sweep it in a uniform way. It will never look like you're inside a sphere.